# AMD 2700X sensors problems

Tags: amd-processor, sensors, lm-sensors

My cpu is AMD Ryzen 2700X (pinnacle ridge), OS is Ubuntu 18.04. 
The problem is that I can't either read fans rpm or read others data.
Have tried on lm-sensors and Xsensors.
The only thing that shows up is `k10temp`.
I know it was something about linux kernel and AMD cpu compatible issues.
Does someone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just built two boxes with 2700x and had the same problem. Update your kernel to 4.16. Follow these instructions. https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/

Comment: I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.10 which using kernel 4.18. But still can't show fans and others sensors compare to Intel's CPU.